# Python Pandas: Adding methods to class pandas.core.series.Series

Tags: python, pandas

I want to work with a time series in Python and, therefore, Pandas' Series class is just perfect and has a lot of useful methods.

Now I want to add some methods that I need and are not implemented. For example, let us say I am interested in adding a method which appends two times one value to the time series, at let us call that method `append2`:

```
import pandas                                                                         
import random                                                                         

class Testclass(pandas.core.series.Series):                                           
        def append2(self, val):                                                       
                return self.append(val).append(val)                                   

dates = pandas.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=72, freq='H')                           
data = [random.randint(20, 100) for x in range(len(dates))]                           
ts = pandas.Series(data, index=dates)                                                 

a = Testclass()                                                                       
b = a.append2(ts[[1]])                                                                

print type(a)                                                                         
print type(b)
```

Now I find that the class of `a` and the class of `b` are different; `b` is a `pandas.core.series.Series` object and therefore you can not apply the method `append2` to it.

I would like `b` to conserve the `append2` method (conserve the same class as `a`). Is that possible? Is there any other way to add methods to the Series class without modifying the source code of the Pandas package?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do something like this. You don't need to sub-class at all, rather just [*monkey-patch*](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/faq.html#adding-features-to-your-pandas-installation). And this would be more efficient that appending twice (as an append copies).

```
In [5]: s = Series(np.arange(5))

In [15]: def append2(self, val):
   ....:     if not isinstance(val, Series):
   ....:         val = Series(val)
   ....:     return concat([ self, val, val ])
   ....: 

In [16]: Series.append2 = append2

In [17]: s.append2(3)
Out[17]: 
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
0    3
0    3
dtype: int64
```